# Not all code paths return a value on Task

Tags: c#

I need to wait for the whole task to finish then return a value. My code gives me an error of "Not all code paths return a value". Could you show me how to fix this? I am confused really with Tasks.

```
 public async override Task<TagInfoReply> GetInfo(TagInfoRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            var tagInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TagInfo>(request.TagInfo);
            var parameter = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParameterGetWhiteListWithEntryInfo>(request.DetectedTag);
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return filters.FilterTags(tagInfo);
            });
            await task.ContinueWith(
                    async antecedent =>
                    {
                        if (antecedent.Result)
                        {
                            var reply = await pcs.GetTagInfo(parameter, tagInfo, TagFilterTime);
                            return new TagInfoReply
                            {
                                FetchedTagInfo = reply
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return new TagInfoReply
                            {
                                FetchedTagInfo = string.Empty
                            };
                        }
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        }
```

If I put in a

```
return new TagInfoReply
                                {
                                    FetchedTagInfo = string.Empty
                                };
```

at the very end and outside the task.ContinueWith, well the error goes away but the problem is when it runs, it doesn't wait for the task to complete. It goes directly to the last return.

Comment: You aren't returning a result from `GetInfo` anywhere that I can see? Solution: return a result from `GetInfo`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I have the return statements in my task.ContinueWith I am thinking that that is enough. Like I said, I really get confused with Tasks.

Comment: Those return statements are in the anonymous method you're passing to `ContinueWith`. They return from the anonymous method, to the calling code within `ContinueWith`.

Comment: I actually kinda get this part. "Those return statements are in the anonymous method you're passing to ContinueWith. They return from the anonymous method, to the calling code within ContinueWith. ". How do I make it so that it waits for the task to finish then return its result. In my "Edit" I said that it goes directly to the last return without waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: Your current code could be rewritten by changing the anonymous method for a real one [like this](https://pastebin.com/u7xK9mSg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your `return` code only returns from the anonymous method you've passed to `ContinueWith`, and they return *to* the calling code within `ContinueWith`. You're not actually returning anything from `GetInfo`.

The result of `ContinueWith` is made available to you as its result, so you should be able to rewrite your code like this:

```cs
public async override Task<TagInfoReply> GetInfo(TagInfoRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var tagInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TagInfo>(request.TagInfo);
    var parameter = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParameterGetWhiteListWithEntryInfo>(request.DetectedTag);
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return filters.FilterTags(tagInfo);
    });
    return await task.ContinueWith(
            async antecedent =>
            {
                if (antecedent.Result)
                {
                    var reply = await pcs.GetTagInfo(parameter, tagInfo, TagFilterTime);
                    return new TagInfoReply
                    {
                        FetchedTagInfo = reply
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new TagInfoReply
                    {
                        FetchedTagInfo = string.Empty
                    };
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

Comment: I tried this too before but this gives me an error of "Since this is an async method, the return expression must be a type TagInfoReply rather than Task<TagInfoReply>. So I change the return type to just TagInfoReply, but it gives me an error of "return type must be Task<TagInfoReply>. I added the ".Result" at "}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion).Result"
Thank you @Llama.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Did you remove an `await` somewhere?

Comment: No I did  not Sir...

Comment: @Ibanez So you have `return await task.ContinueWith`, and didn't accidentally use `return task.ContinueWith`?

Comment: Yes Sir. I did use return await task.ContinueWith.

Answer (score 1):

The core of your problem is that you need to return a value. A side problem is that you shouldn't be using `ContinueWith` at all. If you replace `ContinueWith` with `await`, then your code becomes much clearer:

```
public async override Task<TagInfoReply> GetInfo(TagInfoRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
  var tagInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TagInfo>(request.TagInfo);
  var parameter = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParameterGetWhiteListWithEntryInfo>(request.DetectedTag);
  var result = await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    var filteredTags = filters.FilterTags(tagInfo);
    if (antecedent.Result)
    {
      var reply = await pcs.GetTagInfo(parameter, tagInfo, TagFilterTime);
      return new TagInfoReply
      {
          FetchedTagInfo = reply
      };
    }
    else
    {
      return new TagInfoReply
      {
          FetchedTagInfo = string.Empty
      };
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

It's also likely that you don't need the `Task.Run` in there:

```
public async override Task<TagInfoReply> GetInfo(TagInfoRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
  var tagInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TagInfo>(request.TagInfo);
  var parameter = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParameterGetWhiteListWithEntryInfo>(request.DetectedTag);
  var filteredTags = filters.FilterTags(tagInfo);
  if (antecedent.Result)
  {
    var reply = await pcs.GetTagInfo(parameter, tagInfo, TagFilterTime);
    return new TagInfoReply
    {
        FetchedTagInfo = reply
    };
  }
  else
  {
    return new TagInfoReply
    {
        FetchedTagInfo = string.Empty
    };
  }
}
```